# Not able to get the duration for walking activity using googleFit api

Tags: android, android-sensors, google-fit

I am working on a fitness android app which shows steps,calories, distance  and walking duration using google fit api. I want to record the duration while user is walking but it always shows duration as 86399999 for activity type 7 which is walking. I have read many posts regarding this, but not able to get the correct values.

Output of the below code is :
DataPoint{[**7, 86399999, 1**]@[1497412800000000000, 1497499199999000000,raw=0,insert=0](d:activity.summary:gms:aggregated d:activity.segment:com.example.manvi.walkmore:session_activity_segment)}

My code is:

```
private void subscribe() 
{   
    Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(mApiClient, DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)
    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                if (status.getStatusCode() == FitnessStatusCodes.SUCCESS_ALREADY_SUBSCRIBED) {
                    Timber.i("Existing subscription for activity detected.");
                } else {
                    Timber.i("Successfully subscribed!");
                }
            } else {
                Timber.i("There was a problem subscribing.");
            }
        }
    });
}


private class FetchDurationDataTask1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, DataReadResult> {
    protected DataReadResult doInBackground(Void... params) {
        DataReadRequest readRequest = queryFitnessData();
        DataReadResult dataReadResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mApiClient, readRequest).await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return dataReadResult;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(DataReadResult aLong) {
        super.onPostExecute(aLong);
        printData(aLong);
    }
}


public void printData(DataReadResult dataReadResult){
    Status status = dataReadResult.getStatus();
    if (status.isSuccess()) {
        boolean walking = false;
        for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResult.getBuckets()) { 
            if (!bucket.getDataSets().isEmpty()) {
                DataSet dataSet = bucket.getDataSets().get(0);
                for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                    for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                        String fieldName = field.getName();
                        if (fieldName != null && fieldName.equals("activity")) {
                            String type = dp.getValue(field).toString();
                            if(type.equals("7")) {
                                    walking = true;
                            }
                            else {
                                walking = false;
                            }
                        }
                        if(fieldName!=null && fieldName.equals("duration")){
                            if(walking == true){
                                String duration = dp.getValue(field).toString();
                                mDuration.setText(duration);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


private DataReadRequest queryFitnessData() {
        Date now = new Date();
        long startTime = DateUtils.beginOfDay(now);
        long endTime = DateUtils.endOfDay(now);

        DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()

                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)
                     .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
        // [END build_read_data_request]

        return readRequest;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any error logs?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have logs now. When i debugged it, this is output i was getting:Output of the below code is : DataPoint{[7, 86399999, 1]@[1497412800000000000, 1497499199999000000,raw=0,insert=0](d:activity.summary:gms:aggregated d:activity.segment:com.example.manvi.walkmore:session_activity_segment)}  where 86399999 was the duration.

Comment: hello @ManviGupta did you find the answers? did you get changes while user is walking? did you find out what is this data `@[1497412800000000000, 1497499199999000000,raw=0,insert=0]` means?